# How to change my Azure AD app to confidential client? (not public client)

Tags: azure, oauth, azure-active-directory

From the document : [Configurable token lifetimes in Azure Active Directory (Public Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes)

It mentioned for "confidential client", the refresh token is "**until-revoked**".

> Confidential
>   clients are applications that can securely store a client password
>   (secret). They can prove that requests are coming from the client
>   application and not from a malicious actor. For example, a web app is
>   a confidential client because it can store a client secret on the web
>   server. It is not exposed. Because these flows are more secure, the
>   default lifetimes of refresh tokens issued to these flows is
>   **until-revoked**, cannot be changed by using policy, and will not be
>   revoked on voluntary password resets.

So, my Azure AD app is Web app, so, how I can change my Azure AD app to "confidential client"? I can't find any app settings in Azure AD to set "confidential client" or "public client".

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

About **[Confidential client][1]**:

> confidential
> Clients capable of maintaining the confidentiality of their credentials (e.g., client implemented on a secure server with
> restricted access to the client credentials), or capable of secure
> client authentication using other means.

This specification has been designed around the following client profiles:

> **web application**
>
> **A web application is a confidential client running on a web server**.
> Resource owners access the client via an HTML user interface rendered
> in a user-agent on the device used by the resource owner.  The client
> credentials as well as any access token issued to the client are
> stored on the web server and are  not exposed to or accessible by the
> resource owner.

It means that Native Application and user-agent-based application are public clients, but web applicaiton is a confidential client.

---

> so, how I can change my Azure AD app to "confidential client"?

**The answer is obvious: If the applicaiton which you created is a Web APP/Web API, it's just a confidential client. Otherwise, it's a public client.** It depends on what kind app did you create.

Hope this helps!
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1

Comment: Thanks, I have a further question: for my confidential client, I assume I can just use function - AcquireTokenSilentAsync from ADAL v3 library to always get a valid token? ( it will automatically get a new token when old token expired by using this forever Refresh Token)

Comment: Hi,@BoxVery. Just for the rule of SO, you'd better open a new question, you can post more detials about your scenario and we can discuss it there.

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in Azure Portal for making an application public of confidential. By default it is set to No, meaning the application is confidential.
[image]